# Uploading file to rest API using JMeter

Tags: post, file-upload, jmeter

Note - I have checked [BlazeMeter Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) which uploads doc as Body Data while I use File Upload tab.

Here is how my request looks -

[image]

On execution I get following Request -

```
POST https://xxx

POST data:
<actual file content, not shown here>

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Accept-Language: en-US
Authorization: bearer <>
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 78920
Host: test-host
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_102)
```

And the request fails with 400 error -

```
Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request
```

Since I am able to carry out file upload using curl, I assume that I missed the some configuration with JMeter. Curl looks as -

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer <>' -F upload_file=@"test.pdf"  'https://xxx'
```

What did I miss in JMeter file upload?

Comment: I have also tried with MIME Type ```multipart/form-data``` but of no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can successfully upload file via curl, why don't you just record the upload through [JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) like:

```
curl -x http://localhost:8888 -X POST --header 'Content-Type....."
```

---

If you still need to build the request manually consider two important bits:

1. You need to check `Use multipart/form-data for POST`.
2. The most significant, you need to supply "Parameter Name", According to [HTTP Request Sampler Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

   > For the POST and PUT method, if there is no file to send, and the name(s) of the parameter(s) are omitted, then the body is created by concatenating all the value(s) of the parameters.

   Looking into [curl command manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) in your case the "Parameter Name" should be `upload_file`

So the final configuration should look like:

[image: File Upload Configuration]

See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for above steps described in details.

Comment: HTTPS Test recorder is to record browser requests and not to convert from curl to JMeter format, is not it?
I checked the multipart/form-data checkbox, added parameter_name as upload_file and but yet get 400 Error.
This is how requests looks -  https://justpaste.it/edit/12989825/54ff7f90

Comment: HTTP(S) Test recorder is to record any HTTP or HTTPS requests no matter of origin. FYI: all the browsers do is sending HTTP requests and rendering responses

Comment: I was using http4 Implementation which failed with 400 error, switching it to java client worked perfect. Thanks for point at recorder too.

Answer (score 2):

Another vote for using the Java implementation in the Advanced tab in Jmeter.  My headers and body were exactly the same between postman and jmeter, but it wouldn't upload my file (got response code 415) until I changed to the Java implementation.

Comment: I wasted a lot of time and you gave the correct answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

My backend server is implemented in Java and in the file upload request I had to select the Impolementation as Java!

[image]

Here is the file upload section
[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the JAVA implementation of HTTP! file uploads are working again for me which haven't worked since 2.13

here's my post else where:
I had same issue...thought jmeter was doing something wrong since this stuff worked for me in 2.13...hasn't worked since version 3. well..saw a post somewhere that said, using the JAVA implementation of HTTP worked. Guess what? it did work for me too!!! I've been struggling trying to dissect every part of the POST. I was doing it right all along, just needed JAVA implementation of HTTP and voila!

hope that helps!