# How to upload a file using REST API Put method using JMeter

Tags: rest, api, upload, jmeter, zip

Context of my query:
Need to test REST API Put method for uploading a file
tool to be used is JMeter.

I can successfully perform the above operation using POSTMAN tool but its not working in JMeter.

Here are the JMeter Request Details;
method: PUT
Path:path
HEADER
Content-Type= multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary${random}

BODY DATA

------WebKitFormBoundary${random}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="C:\temp\abc.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

------WebKitFormBoundary${random}--

RESULTS:
{"success":false,"errorMessages":"Request did not include an attachment"}
Response code = 400

Appreciate if anyone can help or provide a better way to upload a file using PUT method.

Thanks,
AB

Comment: If I remove the content encoding as given in the question the response is "{"success":false,"errorMessages":"Request did not include an attachment"}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file to rest API using JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570205/uploading-file-to-rest-api-using-jmeter)

Comment: @Kirti - The link you suggest is for POST method and my query is for PUT method.

Comment: yes, you need to change Method field from POST to PUT. But otherwise this question is duplicate, unless you provide more details, or tell us what didn't work when you tried that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use MIME Type: `application/zip`

Your File Upload settings should look like this in JMeter:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you simply don't pass the file you are trying to upload along with the request. If you are building the request manually you will need to add the body of the file to your request using i.e. [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function. Check out [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

---

Also given your request works in Postman you should be able to capture it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Copy the file you will be uploading using Postman to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Start JMeter's Proxy server. Refer [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide to learn how to do it.
3. [Start Postman using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder as a proxy](http://blog.eviltester.com/2016/12/how-to-configure-postman-native-client.html) by passing `--proxy-server` option to it like:

   ```
   C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Postman\app-x.x.x\Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
   ```
4. Execute your request in Postman
5. JMeter will store the captured request under Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller